# .Remove(); does not Remove and .Save(); does set asmv infront of every Node

Tags: c#, xml

as I said in the Title:

`.Remove();` does not Remove

and

`.Save();` does set `asmv2` infront of every node

Code:

```
private void DeleteXmlPopulates()
    {
        string filePath = "C:\\Example\\Example.exe.manifest"
        var xml = XElement.Load(filePath);
        xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").Remove();
        xml.Save(filePath);
    }
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="Example.exe" version="6.1.0.0" publicKeyToken="7f785aa0b92a51a3" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" />
<description asmv2:iconFile="Example.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
<application />
<entryPoint>
<assemblyIdentity name="Example" version="6.1.0.14132" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" />
<commandLine file="Example.exe" parameters="" />
</entryPoint>
<trustInfo>
<security>
<applicationRequestMinimum>
<PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
<defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
</applicationRequestMinimum>
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">    
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
<dependency>
<dependentOS>
  <osVersionInfo>
    <os majorVersion="5" minorVersion="1" buildNumber="2600" servicePackMajor="0" />
  </osVersionInfo>
</dependentOS>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install">
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

there is a comment in the Xml file : `UAC Manifest Options If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following. <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" /> <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" /> If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.`

How the Code shall look like: (just the dependency part , the remaining Part shall be the same)

```
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite" allowDelayedBinding="true">
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

How the Code does look like: (just the dependency part , the remaining Part has asmv2 infront of every node)

```
<asmv2:dependency>
<asmv2:dependentAssembly dependencyType="preRequisite">
</asmv2:dependentAssembly>
</asmv2:dependency>

<asmv2:dependency>
<asmv2:dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" >
</asmv2:dependency>
</asmv2:dependentAssembly>
```

Ok, the more important question (respectively the question We shall try to answer) is why does `.Save();` set `asmv2:` infront of every node?
If thats normal with the Method `.Save();`then I'm surprised because the File cannot be oppened anymore with [MageUI.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx)

How could I solve this Problem or avoid it?

I would appreciate constructive criticism :)

Comment: I strongly suspect that's not the *complete* file. I strongly suspect there's something declaring the `asmv2` namespace alias somewhere... and that's why it's not finding any elements to remove.

Comment: <asmv1:assembly xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"> is in the every manifest file created by the MageUI.exe/Mage.exe. But bevore i  Save it it does not have any asmv2 in it (except the upper node)

Comment: Right, that's not at all what you posted, is it? We can't help you if you don't give us representative input... Please edit your question with the *actual* XML.

Comment: Try adding a namespace. Or use like x.Name.LocalName

Comment: @JonSkeet i hope i edited in your favor :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a classic example of -

[Mixed Declarative Code/Imperative Code Bugs (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387088(v=vs.110).aspx)

You are removing item and at the same time performing query over them, but the `Save` works as it does not have any such problem.

```
xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").Remove();
```

You should try to use a separate list to remove them. As mention in MSDN here -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove(v=vs.110).aspx

> In LINQ to XML programming, you should not manipulate or modify a set
>   of nodes while you are querying for nodes in that set. In practical
>   terms, this means that you should not iterate over a set of nodes and
>   remove them. Instead, you should materialize them into a List by
>   using the ToList extension method. Then, you can iterate over
>   the list to remove the nodes. For more information, see Mixed
>   Declarative Code/Imperative Code Bugs (LINQ to XML).
>
> Alternatively, if
>   you want to remove a set of nodes, it is recommended that you use the
>   Extensions.Remove method. This method copies the nodes to a list, and
>   then iterates over the list to remove the nodes.

The ideal solution would be something similar to this -

```
var itemsToRemove = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install").ToList();
itemsToRemove.Remove();
```

Example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: how could it be possible that i do not get any items in itemstoremove? that means there is no item with this name... y but why its there ...

Answer (score 0):

Your XML has default namespace (`xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"`). You need to use "*`XNamespace` + element name*" to reference an element in namespace :

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2";
xml.Descendants()
   .Where(x => x.Name == ns+"dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")
   .Remove();
```

or just ignore the namespace by using `XElement.Name.LocalName`

```
xml.Descendants()
   .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dependentAssembly" && (string)x.Attribute("dependencyType") == "install")
   .Remove();
```

Comment: The manifest file is still not open-able :/ and that because .save(); does add `asmv2:PermissionSet`